# iosアプリのIPv6対応について

Tags: ios, unity3d, ipv6

６月１日からAppleでのアプリ審査でIPv6 only Network環境での動作チェックがはじまりました。
事前にその対応について備えていたのですが、いざ申請すると「IPv6では接続できないから却下」という旨の返答があり、審査が通過できない状態にあります。
以下、行った対応です。

・Unityのバージョンを4.6.5から4.7.2へ変更　※Unityから公式にアナウンスがあったバージョン
・Appleが通信できない、という指摘が入ったのはUnity標準の「WWW」クラスを使った通信箇所。
・その他Appleからアナウンスがあった利用できない関数の確認

Appleにも質問を投げているのですが、クラッシュログを提出しないと答えない旨きています。
現在、こちらの環境では

･NAT64環境で接続テスト、こちらの環境では正常に動作している
※パケットモニターでIPv6になっているのも確認できています。

上記のようになっており、エラーすら把握できない状態にあります。

原因としては
・こちらが用意した環境が不適切である可能性
・導入しているプラグインが対応していない可能性(こちらは別途問い合わせ中)
が考えられますが、何から手をつけていいかわからず、八方塞です。

どなたか知恵をかしていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

iOS・Macともに指定されたバージョンへの更新は完了しています。

※一部文章に間違いがあったので訂正しました

**2016/06/20 追記**

相変わらずリジェクトを受けていますが、
サーバーを「Appleからのアクセス」だけを限定した処理に切り分け、
審査を提出しました。
結果もIPv6で接続できない、という返答にかわりはなかったですが、
通信が成功している場合もありました。
※IPv6での接続ができている証拠かと思います。

Comment: プラグインについては関係なさそうでした。ためしにはずして審査しましたが、同様の返答になりました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

同様の不具合を訴えている方がAppleのフォーラムにいます。

"Pass the NAT64 IPv6 test but App Store rejected the build"
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48314

> We follow the guideline to setup the IPv6 NAT64 environment to test our app works in the IPv6 NAT64 network.
>
> In the iOS Wi-fi setting it shows DNS 2001:2:0:aab1::1 and IP address shows 169.254.61.21, which should be correct based on another thread from the reply of this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/140901#140901 And our app works fine in the testing environment. However, our app still got rejected due to network problem in the reviewer's testing environement. We cannot replicate the problem and would like to post this to see if anybody having similar issue.
>
> We use AFNetworking 3.1 to issue the HTTP requests and test for reachability, which should be based on NSURLSession and fully support IPv6. We grepped the code and are sure that we don't have any IPv4 address in the code base. We are thinking to do Packet Capture to debug our case, but in the meantime we would also like to ask here to see if anybody could point out that potentital root of cause of the rejection.

また、その中で審査通過したという人もいましたが・・

> I believe they have been using an invalid test environment with IPv4 turned off.  Mine was rejected for the same reason, but approved this morning with no changes on my part.

上記のような人もいるので、本件についてはApple側の環境に問題がある可能性もあります。
おそらく、アプリ側をいじってどうこうできる問題ではないので、UnityフォーラムのIPv6スレッドに相談するか、App Review Boardでご自身の検証した環境の説明をされてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。Unityフォーラムにもう一度相談なげてみようと思います(一旦あげましたが、適切じゃない気がして削除しました)。　App Review Boardには環境の説明も含め、対応をしましたが"NAT64の説明はここに書いてるからこの通りにしてくれ"の一点張りでダメでした。

Comment: IPv6環境で動作している所を動画で撮影して提出するということはされていますか？
メッセージのやり取りでは埒が明かないというパターンは多いです。

Comment: いえ、していません。
一度動画を撮影して試してみたく思います。
※IPv6で確認していますよ、という証明については設定画面だけでよいのか不安なところです。

Comment: この返答で教えていただいたAppleのフォーラムにその記載がありました。こちらで対応を進めたく思います。

Comment: ダメでした。接続できないから許可しない、という返答でした。

Comment: 解決できていませんが、当解答が最も答えになっていましたので、こちらで一旦完了とします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

「WWWかUnityWebRequest APIだけを使用している場合は問題ありません」と書いてありますがダメなんですね。
http://blogs.unity3d.com/jp/2016/05/10/unity-and-ipv6-support/

Comment: はい、ダメでした。
何故だめなのか、と陥っているのもそこが大きく関わってます。

Comment: 接続先の指定をドメイン名を使わずIPv4のIPで直接指定しているとか

Comment: いえ、それもないです。全てドメインで指定しています。
※IPアドレスの正規表現で検索し、知らぬところで使われているというケースもなかったです。