# MacのNAT64について

Tags: macos, iphone, ipv6

Appleのアプリ審査にて、IPv6対応が義務付けられました。
その対応のため、NAT64設定をし、動作検証をしています。
ただしAppleの環境だとNGということでした。
そのため、以下の対応内容で問題がないか確認がしたいです。

**対応したこと**

・MacOSを対象のOSへアップデート
・有線LANのMacの共有を指示された設定で対応。
Wi-Fiの設定、[NAT64ネットワークを作成]にチェック
他のWi-Fiのアクセス設定はすべて削除
・iPhone(9.3.2)でその環境でアクセスできるよう設定
・ネットワークの環境をiPhoneで確認し、DNSがIPv6のアドレス(2001:～)になっていることを確認
・設定についてAppleに問い合わせをしたが、設定のリンクが送られる、手順を細かく記載して質問をしたが1週間が経過した今も返答なし

**確認したこと**

・設定前、設定後をそれぞれパケットモニターでIPv6でDNSへ問い合わせしていることは確認
・インターネットが接続できることも確認

八方塞で、非常に困っています。
お手数をおかけしますが、お願いいたします。

**関連のリンク**
[Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)

**関連の質問**
[iosアプリのIPv6対応について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26783/ios%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AEipv6%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
自身が対応した内容で問題なかったようでした。